# Rails 4 .where nested model search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, model

**Hi,**

I have a Model of Users and a Model of Products.
My Model Products belongs_to my Model User and a User has_many Products.

My question is how can i search 1 or multiple products matching a user attribute?

exemple: `Product.where(price: 10) for user.where(id: 2)`

What is the solution for nested model search, i'm a bit lost.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since products belongs to user (and user has_many products), you can query off of the relation:

```
user = User.find(2)
products = user.products.where(price: 10)
```

Comment: Ok, but it's working only for one user.
If i say 

`users = User.where(happy: true)
products = users.products.where(price: 10)`

I get a 'NoMethodError: undefined method'

Comment: ok i found the solution:
`users = User.where(happy: true)
products = users.map {|u| u.products.where(price: 10)}`